# How do I incorporate Geolocation into the Google Places API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**I want to:**

- Render a google map on a web page;
- Have the map centre on a user's current location;
- Show places local to that user.

**Question**: Assuming this is possible (and that the limiting factor is my *current* ability), how might this be achieved?

**Resources**:

I am using the [Google Maps JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) v3 and [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search)

Currently, I can achieve *either* rendering places around a hardcoded location or centring the map on the user.

I have used [this Geolocation code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) and this [Places Search code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search) assuming that I could integrate the code of one into the other (by handing lat/long values from the geolocator into the location object `pyrmont`).

There exists a SO question on this for Google Maps API v2, deprecated by v3.

Comment: what is your goal or want to achieve (marker, name of place in geolocation code or geolocation in place search)

Comment: in place search I integrated geolocation code . result is https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/cmg1t0gs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to do is define the map:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

this tells us that we are using the places library and on callback we are going to call the `initMap` function.

```
function initMap() {
  var london = {
    lat: 51.5073509,
    lng: -0.12775829999998223
  };
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      london = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      map.setCenter(london);
      setPlaces(london);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation   
    //since you set coords above this section it will default to that
    setPlaces(london);      
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: london,
    zoom: 15
  });      
}
```

The `initMap` function initialises the map. We set `var london` to the co-ordinates of London in case the user does not have location turned on.

We then check to see if their location is turned on `if (navigator.geolocation) {`does this. if this is true then we override `london` to the users position. If changed we then move the map to the users location.

both outcomes will call:

```
function setPlaces(location) {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: location,
    radius: 1000,
    type: ['store']
  }, callback);
}
```

Which gets the places around the location (either user or predefined)

A working example can be seen here, for parameters etc just read the API.

**JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/4kgy68rg/1/**